# rbenv: bundle: command not found

Tags: ruby, bundler

I am trying create bosh release using command

```
bosh create release --force --final --with-tarball
```

I got following error

```
Error:  
     > + bundle package --all
     > rbenv: bundle: command not found
     >
     > The `bundle' command exists in these Ruby versions:
     >   2.2.4
     'admin_ui' pre-packaging failed
```

In my Linux machine following version of software is installed.

```
which ruby
/root/.rbenv/shims/ruby

ruby --version
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155)

which bundle
/root/.rbenv/shims/bundle

bundle --version
Bundler version 1.11.2
```

**Update:**
    ~/.profile file

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

I source this file before creating bosh release

error:

```
> Using membrane 0.0.5
  > Installing mime-types-data 3.2015.1120
  >
  > Gem::InstallError: mime-types-data requires Ruby version >= 2.0.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `bosh` runs in it’s own environment (read: it does not load all your `.bashrc` etc configs.)

One might try to put what is `rbenv`-related into `~/.profile` file (it should be read by `bosh`,) or try another way to tell `bosh` about the environment.

Comment: I am not familiar with `bosh`, I am not sure, what shell config does it read, or has it it’s own config. Please try to add the same two strings into `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` or (preferred way) into `bosh`’s environment config, if it has one.